# Typo3 7LTS: How to use Paginationwidget with "lib.dynamicContent"

Tags: typoscript, dynamic-content, typo3-7.6.x

Hi have a problem to generate the Pagination with a dynamicContent. I created my own partial with help of bootstrap_package.

```
temp.pageIds = HMENU
temp.pageIds.entryLevel = 2
temp.pageIds.1 = TMENU
temp.pageIds.1 {
    NO.stdWrap.field = uid
    NO.allWrap = |,
    NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
}

lib.rmDynamicContent = CONTENT
lib.rmDynamicContent = CONTENT
lib.rmDynamicContent {

    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList.cObject < temp.pageIds
        orderBy = sorting
        max = 10
    }
}
```

the pageIds are all which are subpages, which i wanna show as blog/news - list. I wanna now to add a Pagination.

My Question is how i can use "f:cObject-Tag" to render it automatic and do the pagination.

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.rmDynamicContent" data="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not really easy to do as you need to do the pagination completly in TypoScript. What about a different solution by rendering all 10 records and do the pagination in JavaScript? That would also be nicer regarding the performance and usability